# Invalid message inline the input

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I try to locate the invalid message inline the input.
I add to the error message `style="display:inline"` But it's not working.

What can I do?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form name="pniyaForm">
   <div class="row form-inline">
      <div class="col-sm-12 form-group has-feedback">
          <label for="mail">Mail:</label>
          <input name="mailParent" ng-class="{'has-error':pniyaForm.$submitted && pniyaForm.mailParent.$invalid}"  id="mail" type="email" ng-model="mailParent"  required/>
      </div>
      <span style="display:inline" ng-show="pniyaForm.mailParent.$invalid && (pniyaForm.mailParent.$dirty || pniyaForm.mailParent.$touched)"  ng-messages="pniyaForm.mailParent.$error">
          <div ng-message="required">required</div>
      </span>
                          
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all you are putting `span` outside of the parent `div class="col-sm-12 form-group has-feedback"` you have to put the `span` inside it, then change `inline` to `inline-block` as the following:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form name="pniyaForm">
  <div class="row form-inline">
    <div class="col-sm-12 form-group has-feedback">
       <label for="mail">Mail:</label>
       <input name="mailParent" ng-class="{'has-error':pniyaForm.$submitted && pniyaForm.mailParent.$invalid}"  id="mail" type="email" ng-model="mailParent"  required/>
                            
       <span style="display:inline-block" ng-show="pniyaForm.mailParent.$invalid && (pniyaForm.mailParent.$dirty || pniyaForm.mailParent.$touched)"  ng-messages="pniyaForm.mailParent.$error">
          <div ng-message="required">required</div>
       </span>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `display: inline-block` to input field and message together.

```
.form-inline > .form-group,.form-inline > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```